# Is there a C library function that returns bool?

Tags: c, boolean

I was wondering, is there any library function (like `printf`, `scanf`, `read`, `malloc`) in C that returns a `bool` type?

Like for example a function to verify actions like comparing strings e.g: (`bool isEqual(char *s, char *s`)) or which number is bigger (`bool AIsBiggerThanB(int a, int b)`). I've been programming in C since 1 year and I've always used 0 and 1, and as we all know, bool was introduced to C in C99. So, is there any new functions along the addition of `stdbool.h` ?

Comment: What did you check?

Comment: Perhaps [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) could be helpful in your search?

Comment: If I wanted to check something, I'd use 0 or 1. I'm asking if with the implementation of stdbool.h, they added new functions returning a bool to the C library

Comment: Why are you interested in a library function that returns a `bool`? what difference does it make?

Comment: I think `true` and `false` is a better visual interpretation than C library functions returning 0 or 1. Also, for a better understanding, I was explaining to someone returning different variable types and their differences

Comment: Some "boolean" standard functions return `0` for "false", but might not necessarily return `1` for "true", it can be any non-zero value. You have to read references or manual pages (or the C specification itself) to know.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Had to ask even if it hasn't been asked before on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, usage of a(ny) new type is not likely to change the existing prototypes / implementations unless there was an error/problem inherently.

That being said, the "Atomics" `<stdatomic.h>` declare some of the functions returning `_Bool`. Check `§7.17` in `C11`, if you need more info on this.